# How to get the path of an action of a controller in Symfony2?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, post, twig

I was practicing symfony2. And i got a problem:

I just made a simple twig page which posts data to an action of the controller, and there is a function(it works):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{ path('my_test_account_register') }}",
    data: account,
    success: function(msg){
        alert("Succeed！");
    },
    error: function(XmlHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert ("Failed! ");
    }
}
```

I don't want to add a annotation to every action of mine, howver. I wanted to replace  `url: "{{ path('my_test_account_register') }}"`  into `url: "{{ path('MyTestBudnle:Account:register') }}"` , but i failed.

My question is: how to specify the url of an action inside a controller? Maybe this is a silly question, and this is my first time to stackoverflow. So, nice to meet you guys!

Comment: why not use routing.yml to specify your route and use them instead of using annotations in every action

Comment: Frankly speaking, i prefer annotations (TωT)ﾉ

Comment: You simply can't use that kind of annotation as Symfony2 standard requires to specify the routing name

Comment: @DonCallisto But I found out that if you are going to render some page, you can just use `{{ render (controller('BlablaBundle:BlaBla:Blabla')) }}`, we can hide our path using this method...

Comment: render `path()` is slightly different from render `controller()` :)

Comment: not intendet to do so.

Comment: If you really don't want to use named routes (which you really should) then generate the url in your controller and pass it to twig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The twig function `path()` you are (correctly) using, creates the url for a given route name and some optional parameters.

A controller can have different routes (and thereby different urls) for the same action. Because of this, you cannot use the `Bundle:Controller:Action` notation, if you want to find out the url for a specific action. Instead, you have to use the route name.

The difference between `path()` and `render()` is, that `render()` includes the response of a subrequest to a specific action into the template. Because this all happens internally, there is no need to generate an url for this. You can even use `render()` with actions, that have no route at all.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use

```
url: Routing.generate('state_list'),
```

Have a look on [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).